# The conjugate representation in $\mathfrak{su}(2)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, eigenvalue

Cheng & Li gives the following problem:

> Let $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ be the bases for the spin-1/2 representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and that for the diagonal operator $T_3$,
>   \begin{align}
> T_3\psi_1 &= \frac{1}{2} \psi_1 \\
> T_3\psi_2 &= -\frac{1}{2}\psi_2
> \end{align}
>   What are the eigenvalues of $T_3$ acting on $\psi_1^*$ and $\psi_2^*$ in the [conjugate representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_representation)?

I originally thought this problem was trivial, just take the complex conjugate of both sides and use the fact that $T_3$ is real valued to get that $T_3\psi_1^* = \frac{1}{2}\psi_1^*$, but this is wrong.

---

If we start from the arbitrary transformation $\psi'_i = U_{ij}\psi_j$ and complex conjugate both sides, we get ${\psi'}_i^* = U_{ij}^* \psi_j^*$. But for traceless Hermitian matrices such as $U$, there exists an $S \in \mathfrak{su}(2)$ such that $S^{-1}US = U^*$, and so, writing the previous equation in matrix form:
\begin{align}
\psi'^* = (S^{-1}US)\psi^* \implies S\psi'^* = U(S\psi^*)
\end{align}
So $S\psi^*$ transforms as $\psi$. It turns out that in the Pauli representation that $S = i\sigma^2$, and so:
\begin{align}
T_3\left(\begin{matrix} \psi_2^* \\ -\psi_1^*\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1/2\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix} \psi_2^* \\ -\psi_1^* \end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}

---

What I don't understand is why we couldn't just take the complex conjugate of both sides? Is this quantity $\psi^*$ **not** the traditional "algebraic" complex conjugate of $\psi$? If so, why could we complex conjugate $\psi'_i = U_{ij}\psi_j$ to get $\psi^*$? I feel like I thought I understood the conjugate representation but I clearly don't and I would appreciate any help understanding it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_representation) of a conjugate representation?

Comment: Related meta question: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6206/2451

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why we couldn't just take the complex conjugate of both sides?

Look at the Lie algebra which all representations need to satisfy,
$$
[T_j,T_k]=i\epsilon_{jkm}T_m . 
$$
The generators are all Hermitean and the structure constants real, so this algebra is invariant under Hermitean conjugation. It is also invariant under similarity transformations $T_j\mapsto S^{-1}T_jS$, which provide useful changes of basis.

Now skip the transposition, and simply complex conjugate instead,
$$
[T^*_j,T^*_k]=-i\epsilon_{jkm}T^*_m . 
$$
Do you have a representation of the algebra? Not really, since the r.h.s. sign difference spoils the broth--it is not quite the same algebra.

But, wait, $-T^*_j$ *do* provide a representation of the algebra. Moreover,  luckily, $-T^*_j=S^{-1}T_j S$,  so this  turns out to be just the original rep in a different basis! The eigenvectors have moved and mutated, so the same eigenvalues are merely interchanged. I assume you have learned how to find *S* for the fundamental rep, since you already used it in upending your doublet *ψ* and slipping in a preferential sign--this is what $\sigma_2$ does.

Now consider the eigenvalues. The eigenvalues of $T_3$ are always paired, $\pm$, for all representations (all spins); and, moreover, all generators may be similarity-rotated to $T_3$. So *S* always exists, and merely scrambles the eigenvalues: all reps are real.

- A small point of notation: You might possibly be alarmed that a $-a^* \sim a$ situation would be called "real", when it is purely imaginary. But pure imaginary is just *i* times real. This is but an artifact of the "physics" choice of the Lie algebra convention, with an *i* in front of the real structure constant in a realization with Hermitean, not real, generators. (The adjoint representation consists of *i* multiplying real structure constants, so $S=1\!\!1$. In the undergraduate classical mechanics "Cartesian basis",  one normalizes away the *i*s to obtain real antisymmetric generators.) So a measly minus sign does not really matter.

This is a "good thing". If you looked at the anticommutator of two generators as above and complex conjugated again, if there were a non vanishing so-called [*d*-coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#Lie_algebra) on the right-hand-side beyond the identity, Hermiticity would require the *i* be missing, and so $-T^*_j$ would not satisfy the same anticommutation relation... there wouldn't be such an S preserving it.

So, for these real representations, *d vanishes* (and the *[anomaly coefficients based on these d](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/362009/66086)s also vanish*, for all representations of SU(2)).

This does not quite happen for the bigger SU(N)s, since *not all* of their representations are real. (You can illustrate this by looking at the eigenvalues of, e.g. the fundamental rep generators of SU(3), the Gell-Mann matrices. Hint: are the eigenvalues of $\lambda_8$ $\pm$-paired as above?) But, as you can see by inspection, the adjoint representation is always a real one (*i* times the real structure constants; and you may know how its eigenvalues are paired).

- ***An "academic aside"***: The conjugation rule for the doublet you illustrated, $(\psi_1, \psi_2)\mapsto (\psi_2^*, -\psi_1^*)$, is especially fortunate in the complex Higgs doublet of the EW SM. It allows you to write it compactly as 
  $$ \Bigl((v+h)1\!\!1 + i \vec{\pi}\cdot \vec{\tau}\Bigr)\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 1\end {array}\right) ~,$$
  upon which its conjugate is but 
  $$ \Bigl((v+h)1\!\!1 + i \vec{\pi}\cdot \vec{\tau}\Bigr)\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\ 0\end {array}\right) ~,$$
  of substantial utility in parsing out the custodial symmetries of the SM.