# How is the $SU(2)_L$ conjugation applied?

Tags: field-theory, standard-model, spinors, electroweak, leptons

I'm reading a paper where they introduce the lepton doublets $L$ and "their $SU(2)_L$ conjugations" $\tilde{L}$, which I'm guessing means
$$
\tilde{L} = i\sigma_2L^*.
$$
After $\textit{vev}$, they end up with an expression involving charge conjugated weyl spinors $\nu_L^c$ and $e_L^c$, which I think are defined as
$$
\nu_L^c = -i\sigma_2\nu_L^* \quad \text{and} \quad e_L^c = i\sigma_2e_L^*,
$$
since it works on Dirac spinors like
$$
\psi^c = -i\gamma_2e_L^*.
$$
But that makes me think that the first equation means
$$
\tilde{L} = i\sigma_2L^* =
\begin{pmatrix}
i\sigma_2\nu_L^* \\ i\sigma_2e_L^*
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and not
$$
\tilde{L} = i\sigma_2L^* = i
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\ i & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\nu_l \\ e_L
\end{pmatrix} = i
\begin{pmatrix}
-e_L^* \\ \nu_L^*
\end{pmatrix},
$$
Like I thought. Which is true? And why exactly?

Comment: You might have conflated two kinds of Pauli matrices, one for Dirac spinor (as in charge conjugation) and another one for weak doublet (as in $SU(2)$ conjugation). Please double check the definition of the $SU(2)$ conjugation you mentioned.

Comment: They don't give the definition in the paper, unfortunately. The definitions I use comes from Schwartz and wikipedia. I don't think they say anything about what kind of Pauli matrix is used.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/139532/the-conjugate-representation-in-mathfraksu2), and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/530929/meaning-of-tilde-sim-above-vector-context-particle-physics?noredirect=1&lq=1).